# Abandoned H2 connection involving linked table

Tags: database-connection, h2, linked-tables

I'm having trouble with an application using H2, seemingly due to database connections being left open. I'm trying to understand if it's H2 leaking the connection or me (I'm aware that it's more likely to be me).

The application has Component1, which creates an in-memory H2 database and starts a TCP server. The H2 database contains a few [linked tables](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#linked_tables) which connect to a separate Oracle database using its JNDI identifier. Component2 connects to this database using JDBC with URL `jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.1.1:5521/mem:db1;`.

In the exception below I've highlighted where I'm getting confused. The trace seems to say that a query was issued by a TCP client (Component2) that required a query of a linked table, and that the query on the linked table is what left the connection open. I do not control how H2 connects to the linked table via JNDI, so I'm inclined to think this is not my fault. I've included a linked table definition below the exception to show how they are created.

Can someone please help me understand who - between me and H2 - is responsible for this abandoned connection, and why?

**Exception**

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace$AbandonedObjectException: DBCP object created 2019-12-10 05:46:16 by the following code was never closed:
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedTrace.setStackTrace(AbandonedTrace.java:139)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool.borrowObject(AbandonedObjectPool.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:311)
    at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:274)
    at org.h2.table.TableLinkConnection.open(TableLinkConnection.java:89)
    at org.h2.table.TableLinkConnection.open(TableLinkConnection.java:76)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getLinkConnection(Database.java:2708)
--> at org.h2.table.TableLink.connect(TableLink.java:96)
    at org.h2.table.TableLink.execute(TableLink.java:535)
    at org.h2.index.LinkedIndex.find(LinkedIndex.java:129)
    at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:132)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:163)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:475)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select$LazyResultQueryFlat.fetchNextRow(Select.java:1882)
    at org.h2.result.LazyResult.hasNext(LazyResult.java:101)
    at org.h2.result.LazyResult.next(LazyResult.java:60)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:742)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:884)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.queryWithoutCacheLazyCheck(Query.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:435)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:397)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:145)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:202)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:335)
--> at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:175)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Linked Table**

```
CREATE LINKED TABLE ora_table (
  'javax.naming.InitialContext',
  'java:comp/env/jdbc/oradb',
  NULL,
  NULL,
  '(
    SELECT field
      FROM table
   )'
)
```

Comment: H2 closes connections to liked tables when such table is dropped or during shutdown process of the database. By default H2 uses only the one connection per linked database, but with `SHARE_LINKED_CONNECTIONS=FALSE` H2 uses one connection per linked table. H2 may also close and reopen the connection if it was broken. Connections aren't closed at the end of the query by design.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov that's good information, but doesn't explain the exception. Can you shed any light on why DBCP is complaining about this connection being left open? This same exception occurs many times, each with a different timestamp indicating when the object was created. The tables are not being dropped and the database is not being restarted. Perhaps with linked tables defined by a query, instead of a remote table name, the single connection rule does not hold true?

Comment: No, it doesn't mater, the single connection is used anyway. In your stack trace there is a some hidden exception in the query, so the old (possibly broken) connection was closed by H2 (ignoring any exceptions), and the new connection is going to be allocated. H2 tries to repeat the query one more time with a new connection, because some drivers may close idle connections automatically. H2 throws the original exception only if the query in the new connection also throws it. But H2 can't open a new connection instead of previously closed one due to exception in the DBCP.